# Is it advisable to develop own PHP log?

Tags: php, logging, monitor

Apache log and PHP log doesn't seem to provide much useful way to monitor performance of my script in **production server**. I was thinking of developing custom log for my script which log the following information:

1. Time.
2. Requested URL.
3. Memory Peak Usage.
4. How long does script take to run.

The log will be stored by file and grouped by it date.

**The questions**

1. Does it dramatically affect the performance for high traffic website? If it only slightly affect, it is worth of trying.
2. Is there any existed library or PHP extension that have already done that?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof).

Comment: I want to log on production server. Is it applicable?

Comment: Yes, it should run on your production server and will provide a web interface displaying its results, memory, CPU, function calls, includes etc.

Comment: This is what you're looking for, @invisal. HXProf was developed by Facebook just for being run in production, as opposed to XDebug.

Answer (score 0):

use [xdbug](http://www.xdebug.org/) + [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) for profiling

but they should be avoided once deployed to server.

and for logging purpose [graylog2](http://graylog2.org/) is great

Comment: I want to log on production server. Is it applicable?

Comment: use of profiling tools on production server is not advisable, but yes you can use logging on production.

Comment: Don't run XDebug on your production server. Use XHProf instead.